# Is there a way to create a custom typecast in c?

Tags: c, casting

I have 2 custom types:

```
struct RGB {
    int8_t R;
    int8_t G;
    int8_t B;
}
typedef int24_t color;
```

And I have a function to transfer from `RGB` to `color`:

```
color GetColor (RGB rgb) {
    return (int24_t)rgb.R*256*256+(int24_t)rgb.G*256+(int24_t)rgb.B;
}
```

Is there a way to define a new typecast, where a cast of an `RGB` variable to a `color` type will automatically use my function?

So that i'll be able to use:

```
RGB c1;
color c2;
...
c2=(color)c1; //c2=GetColor(c1);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to? Since such a cast generally doesn't compile there is little chance of inadvertently failing to call the conversion function explicitly.

Comment: It's more elegant in the code.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder -- it would be objectively more unclear though (the user has to look up what's happening behind the scenes). That critique is sometimes brought forth against operator overloading in C++. The use of c style casts which do not explicitly state the taken action (conversion, static cast, dynamic cast, reinterpret cast) is generally fround upon in C++ for the same obfuscating reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's none. If you don't want to call the function, you could convert `GetColor` to a macro:

```
#define GET_COLOR(x) ((x).R*256*256 + (x).G*256 + (x).B)

RGB   c1;
color c2;

c2 = GET_COLOR(c1);
```

---

Another way for this special case would be to put the two structures in a union.

**However, whether this works or not depends highly on your compiler/machine because of alignment, padding etc. This might not be portable and therefore is discouraged.**

You have been warned, example comes here:

```
struct RGB {
    int8_t R;
    int8_t G;
    int8_t B;
}
typedef int24_t color;

typedef union _u_color {
    RGB     rgb;
    color   c24;
} u_color;
```

The you could do

```
RGB   c1 = {0x00, 0xFF, 0xAA};
u_color mycolor;
mycolor.rgb = c1;
c2 = mycolor.c24;
```

Comment: alwas use brackets in macro definitions, or strange things might happen. Here: `#define GET_COLOR(x) ((x).R*256*256 + (x).G*256 + (x).B)`

Comment: please add some brackets around the whole expression, too (although it might not make too much sense for colors, think aobut sth. like `GET_COLOR(x) * 42`

Comment: Be aware that the union may not work as expected due to endian and alignment/padding issues. This solution is highly implementation dependant.

Comment: @harald: yep. Added disclaimer to answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that'd be magic. C doesn't do more magic than absolutely necessary.

If you want to do actual, user-defined *work*, expect to use a function call in C. This is often considered one of the languages's core features.

What you can do is perhaps use horrible `union` magic to make two "views" of the same bits available, but that's rather scary, not very portable, and not recommended.